# Listing is mixed up with the text in second column

Tags: listings, two-column, double-sided, adjustbox

I have the following long listing. I used an `adjustbox` to fit the lines and added `[float=*]` to the listing properties in order to fit it into two columns. I am using [this](https://academic.oup.com/DocumentLibrary/comjnl/comjnl_latexprep2.zip) template which is a two column based article. The problem is shown in the photo below. How to prevent this to happen?

**MWE**

```
   \documentclass{comjnl}

    \usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\shortauthors{jd}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[50]
\lstset{
frame = single}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Regular expression used to extract links within HTML code of Web pages},label=Pattern,linewidth=12cm]

"https?://(?:www\\.)?[^\\n<>\"]+(?:\"[^<]*>([^<]*))?"

\end{lstlisting}
\lipsum[50]
       \begin{strip}
    \centering
\centering
          \adjustbox{width=\textwidth, frame}{

    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={A demonstration of a hierarchical XML file used in this experiment to evaluate our framework.},label=Layers,linewidth=20cm][float=*]
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <crawledURLs>
       <URL adr="http://www.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/publish/csen/index.html" id="0" info="">
         <URL adr="http://www.tsinghua.edu.cn title=" id="1" info=""/>
        -<URL adr="http://ss.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" id="2" info="2017 Deep Learning Summer School">
          <url ADR="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" ID="0" INFO=""/>
          <url ADR="http://fontawesome.io/examples/ --" ID="1" INFO=""/>
          <url ADR="http://www.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/publish/csen/index.html" ID="2" INFO=""/>
          <url ADR="http://www.tsinghua.edu.cn/publish/newthuen/newthuen_cnt/about-th/about-1.html" ID="3" INFO=""/>
        </URL>
        -<URL adr="http://thu-cmu.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" id="3" info="Tsinghua-CMU Double Master Degree Progra...">
          <url ADR="http://tv.tsinghua.edu.cn/folder1/folder20/2011/04/2011-04-215.html" ID="1" INFO=""/>
          <url ADR="http://tv.tsinghua.edu.cn/folder1/folder20/2011/04/2011-04-215.html" ID="2" INFO="Tsinghua University Introduction"/>
          <url ADR="http://www.tudou.com/programs/view/guyM0hdQNi4/?phd=99" ID="3" INFO=""/>
          <url ADR="http://tv.tsinghua.edu.cn/folder1/folder20/2011/04/2011-04-215.html" ID="4" INFO="Campus Tour"/>
          <url ADR="http://www.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/" ID="5" INFO="DCST"/>
          <url ADR="http://www.cmu.edu/index.shtml" ID="6" INFO="Carnegie Mellon University"/>
          <url ADR="http://www.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/" ID="7" INFO="Tsinghua CS Department"/>
          <url ADR="http://www.cmu.edu/index.shtml" ID="8" INFO="CMU"/>
          <url ADR="http://www.tsinghua.edu.cn/publish/th/index.html" ID="9" INFO="Tsinghua University"/>
         </URL>
        -<URL adr="http://ac.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" id="4" info="Advanced Computing Master Program">
          <url ADR="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" ID="0" INFO=""/>
          <url ADR="http://gradadmission.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="1" INFO="Apply Now"/>
          <url ADR="http://gradadmission.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="2" INFO="Apply Now"/>
          <url ADR="http://gradadmission.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="3" INFO="Apply"/>
          <url ADR="http://clem109.com" ID="4" INFO="clem109"/>
         </URL>
         <URL adr="http://www.csai.tsinghua.edu.cn/homepage.shtm" id="5" info="State Key Lab of Intelligence Techonoly ..."/>
         <URL adr="http://media.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/en/" id="6" info="Institute of HCI & Media Integration"/>
        -<URL adr="http://soft.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/English/index.html" id="7" info="Institute of Computer Software">
          <url ADR="http://dbgroup.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="1" INFO="Data Engineering"/>
          <url ADR="http://keg.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="2" INFO="Knowledge Engineering"/>
          <url ADR="http://166.111.68.91" ID="3" INFO="Design Automation of Computer and VLSI Circuits"/>
          <url ADR="http://vis.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="4" INFO="Visualization and Computer Graphics"/>
          <url ADR="http://soft.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/soft/" ID="5" INFO="Software Engineering and System Software"/>
          <url ADR="http://dbgroup.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="6" INFO="Data Engineering"/>
          <url ADR="http://keg.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="7" INFO="Knowledge Engineering"/>
          <url ADR="http://166.111.68.91" ID="8" INFO="Design Automation of Computer and VLSI Circuit"/>
          <url ADR="http://vis.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="9" INFO="Visualization Technology and Computer Graphics"/>
        </URL>
        <URL adr="http://network.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" id="8" info="Institute of Computer Networks"/>
       </URL>
     </crawledURLs>
    \end{lstlisting}
     }
\end{strip}

\lipsum[50]
\lipsum[50]
\lipsum[50]
\lipsum[50]
\lipsum[50]
    \end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Based on the answer provided below, the result will be like this. That is the whole point of using adjustbox to let the listing to be adjusted in a box~!

[image]

**EDIT 2**

When I replace the answer of Zarko with the code in my original project, the adjustbox appears to be rendered as below:

[image]

**EDIT 3**
I have checked my original project and I have realized that the problem is caused due to the fact that I have another listing before it. I have edited MWE and added the first listing to it. Compiling new MWE will result into the following snapshot:

[image]

Comment: seems like the `float*` isn't quite working, could you post a complete MWE with `\begin{document}` and all ?

Comment: @EladDen sure but you need to download the package as I mentioned within my question.

Comment: No problem, as long as we have something we can compile and check :)

Comment: @EladDen take a look now, please.

Comment: @Zarko but it will be limited to one column. I want it to occupy both column. Just like `figure*` or `table*`.

Comment: if you not liked some answer, you not need to down vote it. just not use it should be enough. if you like to have in over two column, than enclose it in `figure*`. is this some problem?

Comment: Can you recast your MWE in terms of a standard document class, for example, `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`?

Comment: How about changing the `\adjustbox` parameter from `\textwidth` to `\linewidth`?  These are the same in 1-coumn mode, but not in multi-column mode.  As in `\adjustbox{max height=\dimexpr\textheight,
               max width=\linewidth}{...}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes that is not good. As I mentioned earlier for the other comment to suggest similar thing, it will limit the listing within a column which makes it unreadable.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I have tested with standard class. It becomes even worse. surrounded in one column and not even stretched to cover both column.

Comment: Then how about a small tweak on `\textwidth` as well as the `linewidth` of the `lstlisting`, as in `\adjustbox{max height=\dimexpr\textheight,
               max width=.95\textwidth}{
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={A demonstration of a hierarchical XML file used in this experiment to evaluate our framework.},label=Layers,linewidth=11cm,][float=*]...    \end{lstlisting}
     }`

Comment: A. The previous listings has nothing to do with it. B. There's no need for adjustbox as the listing float has its own adjustments. C. If you remove the linewidth option and add linebreak then the float is fine. D. the `float=*` should be in the same option brackets as the rest of the options.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `\adjustbox`, the `float=*` should be in the lstlisting definition. It is a big float, so LaTeX pushes it to a page of its own. I used the floatbarrier just to show it is a floating float.

```
\documentclass{comjnl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{placeins}
%\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\shortauthors{jd}
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\lipsum[1-3]



\lstset{frame = single,
        language=XML,
        framexleftmargin=10pt,
        basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
        breaklines=true}


\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A demonstration of a hierarchical XML file used in this experiment to evaluate our framework.},label=Layers,float=*]
   % <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <crawledURLs>
       <URL adr="http://www.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/publish/csen/index.html" id="0" info="">
         <URL adr="http://www.tsinghua.edu.cn title=" id="1" info=""/>
        -<URL adr="http://ss.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" id="2" info="2017 Deep Learning Summer School">
          <url ADR="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" ID="0" INFO=""/>
          <url ADR="http://fontawesome.io/examples/ --" ID="1" INFO=""/>
          <url ADR="http://www.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/publish/csen/index.html" ID="2" INFO=""/>
          <url ADR="http://www.tsinghua.edu.cn/publish/newthuen/newthuen_cnt/about-th/about-1.html" ID="3" INFO=""/>
        </URL>
        -<URL adr="http://thu-cmu.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" id="3" info="Tsinghua-CMU Double Master Degree Progra...">
          <url ADR="http://tv.tsinghua.edu.cn/folder1/folder20/2011/04/2011-04-215.html" ID="1" INFO=""/>
          <url ADR="http://tv.tsinghua.edu.cn/folder1/folder20/2011/04/2011-04-215.html" ID="2" INFO="Tsinghua University Introduction"/>
          <url ADR="http://www.tudou.com/programs/view/guyM0hdQNi4/?phd=99" ID="3" INFO=""/>
          <url ADR="http://tv.tsinghua.edu.cn/folder1/folder20/2011/04/2011-04-215.html" ID="4" INFO="Campus Tour"/>
          <url ADR="http://www.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/" ID="5" INFO="DCST"/>
          <url ADR="http://www.cmu.edu/index.shtml" ID="6" INFO="Carnegie Mellon University"/>
          <url ADR="http://www.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/" ID="7" INFO="Tsinghua CS Department"/>
          <url ADR="http://www.cmu.edu/index.shtml" ID="8" INFO="CMU"/>
          <url ADR="http://www.tsinghua.edu.cn/publish/th/index.html" ID="9" INFO="Tsinghua University"/>
         </URL>
        -<URL adr="http://ac.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" id="4" info="Advanced Computing Master Program">
          <url ADR="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" ID="0" INFO=""/>
          <url ADR="http://gradadmission.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="1" INFO="Apply Now"/>
          <url ADR="http://gradadmission.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="2" INFO="Apply Now"/>
          <url ADR="http://gradadmission.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="3" INFO="Apply"/>
          <url ADR="http://clem109.com" ID="4" INFO="clem109"/>
         </URL>
         <URL adr="http://www.csai.tsinghua.edu.cn/homepage.shtm" id="5" info="State Key Lab of Intelligence Techonoly ..."/>
         <URL adr="http://media.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/en/" id="6" info="Institute of HCI & Media Integration"/>
        -<URL adr="http://soft.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/English/index.html" id="7" info="Institute of Computer Software">
          <url ADR="http://dbgroup.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="1" INFO="Data Engineering"/>
          <url ADR="http://keg.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="2" INFO="Knowledge Engineering"/>
          <url ADR="http://166.111.68.91" ID="3" INFO="Design Automation of Computer and VLSI Circuits"/>
          <url ADR="http://vis.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="4" INFO="Visualization and Computer Graphics"/>
          <url ADR="http://soft.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/soft/" ID="5" INFO="Software Engineering and System Software"/>
          <url ADR="http://dbgroup.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="6" INFO="Data Engineering"/>
          <url ADR="http://keg.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="7" INFO="Knowledge Engineering"/>
          <url ADR="http://166.111.68.91" ID="8" INFO="Design Automation of Computer and VLSI Circuit"/>
          <url ADR="http://vis.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" ID="9" INFO="Visualization Technology and Computer Graphics"/>
        </URL>
        <URL adr="http://network.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn" id="8" info="Institute of Computer Networks"/>
       </URL>
     </crawledURLs>
    \end{lstlisting}




\FloatBarrier

\lipsum[50]

\lipsum[50]

\lipsum[50]

\lipsum[50]

\lipsum[50]
\end{document}
```

EDIT:

AND THE RESULT
[image]

Comment: did you even compile it? if so, you will notice the reason for using adjustbox.however, I have updated my question.

Comment: I did compile it, and it worked out just fine. Try my MWE AS IS, see what happens, then put it in your code, there might be something else there